# Rails 3 controller ignores parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, parameter-passing

```
class TagController < ApplicationController

 def show
  @videos = Video.tagged_with(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
  end
 end

end
```

Log:

```
Started GET "/tag/node.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-13 23:10:59 +0100
Processing by TagController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"node"}
```

Currently I'm passing `node.js` as the value for my `params[:id]` but somehow ( and according to the logs) my app is passing only `node` as parameter value.

How can I make sure that the value `node.js` is passed into my controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the `(.:format)` in the routes is being eaten up by Rails; the `.js` is being used to determine the format.

So, a simple fix for this could be:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.js   { render <erb file used for html> }
end
```

But, that does not "feel" right, since you're using the `format` to return something that is not of that format (we are returning HTML when `.js` is requested)

If you can, you should alter the "node.js" to some other value like "node_js". Else, look into using [`parse_query` or `parse_nested_query` in Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L47).

Or you could define/re-define the route without the `(.:format)` tacked on to the end.